# Tree buried in flower bed

Tags: trees, flowers, tree-removal

[image]
[image]

Pictures are parts of tree I got out so far and tree still remaining in ground

went to dig a hole for a bush, and found a tree root. I went to dig it out and the more I dug, it seems like someone buried a whole tree! I’ve removed about a 10 foot section of it so far, but there seems to be even more and I have no idea how large this actually is. Do you think it is imperative that I remove it?

Comment: Is it a real tree or some remains of construction material (or beams of an old farm). What it is the status of it? (rot or still strong). And what kind of bush? Roses may have less problems then e.g. some bushes with deeper roots (e.g. used for edges).

Comment: A picture would help us answer your question.

Comment: More likely it grew there from a tree nearby, if it's actually a tree root. What's around for trees? Are you quite sure it's not a pipe or cable?

Comment: No worries. Stop digging. Deep, fat roots of a tree are there to anchor the tree and seek water. They do not compete with shrubs for nutrients.

Comment: No it’s an actual buried tree. There are no other trees around and it’s not just roots. It’s like the full trunk. Maybe a birch tree. It seems to be buried 6-10 inches under ground. I feel like I’m getting to a part where there’s more decay and looks like things have been living off it. The only info I could find is it’s bad to bury stumps because of infestation and air pockets created.

Comment: I’m not sure how to add photos from my phone on here ‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: Sounds like someone tried to create a Hügukultur garden see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCgelkultur) for more info.

Comment: @Shelly9226 use the [edit] function, then the little photo icon amongst the other icons on the input field. The pop up should guide you through the steps. Note that there’s an upper size limit, so you may have to use a smaller resolution photo.

Comment: It looks like you added one photo, and then accidentally removed both inside the post when trying to add a second one, so I just quickly readded them.